# Extracting data from an XML

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've looked at several examples and haven't been able to edit one to fit my needs.. I'm trying to extract the maker and model tags from a file but no matter what previously answered question I find I can't get it to work for me.

Edit- It's probably not different. What's different is my level of understanding of python. Trying to edit the scripts provided in the different answers already on Stack, I've been unable to successfully get the thing to work.

```
<camera>
   <maker>Fujifilm</maker>
    <model>GFX 50S</model>
    <mount>Fujifilm G</mount>
    <cropfactor>0.79</cropfactor>
</camera>
```

Comment: Look for `BeautifulSoup` library. On the internet there are plenty of documentation

Comment: IT very well may be but I couldn't figure out how to properly edit it to get the results I needed. Was hoping someone could help provide the specifics....My knowledge of python is at a beginner level but I need to do this for a proposal and don't want to just copy/paste them all.

Comment: I hate to lose rep over this but it's just something I don't understand and trying ot edit the different solutions posted have yielded no results.

Comment: try xmltodict
<code>import xmltodict

with open('c:\\temp\data.xml') as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
    print(doc['camera']['maker'])
    print(doc['camera']['model'])

https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/xml/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try bs4...?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = '''
        <camera>
            <maker>Fujifilm</maker>
            <model>GFX 50S</model>
            <mount>Fujifilm G</mount>
            <cropfactor>0.79</cropfactor>
        </camera>
        '''

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
make = soup.find('maker')
model = soup.find('model')
print(f'Make: {make.text}\nModel: {model.text}')
```

for multiple entries, just loop through them with find_all()

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = '''
        <camera>
            <maker>Fujifilm</maker>
            <model>GFX 50S</model>
            <mount>Fujifilm G</mount>
            <cropfactor>0.79</cropfactor>
        </camera>
        <camera>
            <maker>thing1</maker>
            <model>thing2</model>
            <mount>Fujifilm G</mount>
            <cropfactor>0.79</cropfactor>
        </camera>
        <camera>
            <maker>thing3</maker>
            <model>thing4</model>
            <mount>Fujifilm G</mount>
            <cropfactor>0.79</cropfactor>
        </camera>
        <camera>
            <maker>thing5</maker>
            <model>thing6</model>
            <mount>Fujifilm G</mount>
            <cropfactor>0.79</cropfactor>
        </camera>
        '''

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
make = soup.find_all('maker')
model = soup.find_all('model')
for x, y in zip(make, model):
    print(f'Make: {x.text}\nModel: {y.text}')
```

getting data through a file:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('path/to/your/file') as file:
    page = file.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
    make = soup.find_all('maker')
    model = soup.find_all('model')
    for x, y in zip(make, model):
        print(f'Make: {x.text}\nModel: {y.text}')
```

without importing any modules:

```
with open('/PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE') as file:

    for line in file:
        for each in line.split():
            if "maker" in each:
                each = each.replace("<maker>", "")
                print(each.replace("</maker>", ""))
```

this is for the 'maker' tag only, it might be beneficial to split these up into separate definitions and iterate through them

Comment: would this work for a file filled with those types of entries? or would I just have to past all the entries inside those quote marks?

Comment: you would need the find_all() function and then you would iterate over all of them

Comment: yeah, use the "with open()" function... try the last bit of code i posted, just replace the 'path/to/your/file' but keep the quotes

Comment: were you able to get this to work? @RobertL78

Comment: I have not had 2 minutes to try yet. I'll be trying over the weekend.. Thank you.

Comment: So I found some time to try this and keep getting the following error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/RobertL/Documents/extract-xml.py", line 5, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'xml')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 165, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?

I've installed beautifulsoup4 and lxml along with msgpack, and six==1.10.0 per other threads.

Comment: using the last method to extract from a file.

Comment: Did you do: “pip install bs4”?

Comment: I did  "pip3 install beautifulsoup4" but just now tried "pip install bs4" but I still get the same error. Both seems to install something and not say it was already installed.

Comment: Hmm... strange, bs4 is the package, try: “pip3 install bs4 -U”

Comment: Installing collected packages: bs4
  Running setup.py install for bs4 ... done
Successfully installed bs4-0.0.1

Same error when running the script though. It should just work without having to reboot or anything I assume.

Comment: No reboot, how are you executing the script, through an IDE, IDLE, etc?

Comment: Yes I'm running it through Idle but in a new window saved with a file name then F5 to run

Comment: That seems to be the problem. I needed to run it from terminal... running from IDLE just kept failing.

Comment: Oh I see, line 5 needs to be...  soup = BeautifulSoup(page, “html.parser”) or soup = BeautifulSoup(page, “lxml”)

Comment: it actually worked without that edit when I ran through terminal. I installed the lxml package. just had to add an extra print() statement to separate the output a bit.

Comment: Nice! Glad everything worked out

Comment: Would it be possible if you don't mind.. to show how to do this without having to import any modules? I'm wondering really if python can do this only with what's included even if the code is longer and less elegant. I'm in an intro to python class and this isn't homework. I just noticing that seasoned people always import modules to make things simpler but I want to know how to do it without modules if at all possible. If you don't fee like it that's okay but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: I gotcha, so I left the 'model' tag untouched, but the 'maker' tag works and filters fine, it might be beneficial for you to look into 'python generators' and create 2 separate functions with this code.  I think that will give you the desired outcome

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
maker = root.findtext('maker')
model = root.findtext('model')
```